# Push back function in python

Tags: python

```
   for (int i=1; i<n+1; i++) {
        vector<String> temp;
        folder = pathName + to_string(i) + "/*.jpg";
        glob(folder, temp);
        filenames.push_back(temp);
    }
```

i want to write this in python. i have managed to do the below code but im struggling with the pushback function.

```
for i in range(1,n):
    print(i)
    folder = path + str(i)
    print folder
    files = [f for f in listdir(folder) if isfile(join(folder, f))]

    #need to push values to a vector (vector<vector<string>>)

    break
```

how can i do the pushback like function in python?

Comment: `files.append(...)`?

Comment: `files.append(...)`. A vector in Python is called a list (and probably not exactly the same thing).

Comment: Python has *great* [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/index.html). I suggest you read it.

Comment: I'd use the `glob()` module here, and either `list.append()` (to add nested lists) or `list.extend()` (to add all *elements* from the globbing result to a list).

Comment: thanks a lot guys (y)

Comment: `help(list)` can be `help`ful. Python's analogue to `push_back` is called `append`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1,n):
    print(i)
    folder = path + str(i)
    print folder
    files = [f for f in listdir(folder) if isfile(join(folder, f))]

    #need to push values to a vector "filenames' (vector<vector<string>>)
    filenames.append(files)
```

so what will this do is same as the push back function in opencv. every time that the vector files (containing file name in a directory) is updated it will pushback to the filenames vector.

Comment: Please add explanations to your answer.

Comment: Better do `filenames.extend(fiels)`. This way `filenames` will be a list of filenames. In your case it will be a list of lists of filenames.